# radial solutions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplacian

I have a question about the following exercise:
Find all radial solutions of
$$
-\Delta u-x\cdot\nabla u=0,\quad x\in\mathbb{R}^3.
$$
How do I express $x\cdot \nabla u$ in spherical coordinates?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$. Then
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\,\frac{\partial r}{\partial x_i}=\frac{x_i}{r}\,\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}.
$$
Then
$$
x\cdot\nabla u=\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\,\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}=\cdots
$$

Comment: A followup hint to this: notice that $\sum_{i=1}^3 \frac{x_i^2}{r} = r$. This will make the whole equation just involve $u$ and $r$.

Comment: Therefore, I only need to solve $\partial_r^2u+(r+2/r)\partial_ru =0$, right?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Find all radial solutions of
$$-\Delta u-x\cdot\nabla u=0,\quad x\in\mathbb{R}^3.$$

- We seek solution in form
  $$u=v\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2\right)=v(t)$$
- $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}=v'(t)\,2\,x_i$$
  $$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_i^2}=v''(t)\,4\,x_i^2+2v'(t)$$
  $$\Delta u=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_i^2}=4v''(t)t+2nv'(t)$$
  $$x\cdot\nabla u=\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\,\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}=
  \sum_{i=1}^nv'(t)2x_i^2=2v'(t)t$$
- Solve ODE
  $$4v''(t)t+(2t+2n)v'(t)=0$$
  $$v(t)=\mathit{C_1}\, \int {\left. \frac{{{e}^{-\frac{t}{2}}}}{{{t}^{\frac{n}{2}}}}dt\right.}+\mathit{C_2}$$
- Answer:
  $$u=\mathit{C_1}\, \int {\left. \frac{{{e}^{-\frac{t}{2}}}}{{{t}^{\frac{n}{2}}}}dt\right.}+\mathit{C_2},\quad t=\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2,\quad n=3.$$